# Performance Optimisation

Tags: vba, performance, excel, optimization

I have this bit of my code which takes like 90 % of the runtime.

There are about 8000 rows and information are stored in column A. This bit of code is splitting this information in the other columns.
It takes approximately 15 mins to run ( :O ).
Any suggestions on how to improve the performance ?

```
For i = 2 To Row_Number ' Loop for each row

    If InStr(Cells(i, 1), "//") = 0 Then ' This means that if // appears somewhere in the text we delete all the rows (including this one) (see Else :) and stop the loop
        j = 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        LongVIN = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 1, j - 1)
        k = j
        j = j + 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Cells(i, 3) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), k + 1, j - k - 1) ' Model
        k = j
        j = j + 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Cells(i, 4) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), k + 1, j - k - 1) ' Dealer
        k = j
        j = j + 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        k = j
        j = j + 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Cells(i, 6) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), k + 1, j - k - 1) ' Region

        k = j
        j = j + 1
        Do Until Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1) = ";"
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        Cells(i, 7) = CDate(Mid(Cells(i, 1), k + 1, j - k - 1)) ' Retail Date
        k = j

        Cells(i, 5) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), k + 1, Len(Cells(i, 1)) - k) '(Len - (k+1) +1) Dealer Name

        Cells(i, 1) = Mid(LongVIN, 1, 10)
        Cells(i, 2) = Mid(LongVIN, 11, 7)

    Else:
        Range("A" & i & ":A" & Row_Number).Delete 'ClearContents
        Exit For

    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see a significant boost in performance by storing the data in an array, operating on the array, and storing the data back into the spreadsheet.

Something like:

```
Dim data As Variant
Dim result As Variant

data = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Row_Number, 1))
Redim result (1 To Row_Number, 1 To 7) As Variant
```

Now instead of reading from `Cells(i, 1)`, you read from `data(i, 1)` and instead of writing to `Cells(i, n)` you write to `result(i, n)`.

And at the end of your code:

```
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Row_Number, 7)) = result
```

Comment: WOW no comment ! It takes less than a second now ! I'll just have to adapt the index. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I would also suggest using `Split()` instead of looping thru string.

Comment: Would there be a way to store for each row (without a second loop) the `Split()` range (which is a 1-D array) in the second dimension of the result array ? So something like this : `result(i-1,:)= Split(Cells(i,1),";")` ? Or would I need a loop to store each element 1 by 1 ? (" : " means all elements...but unvalid in VBA I fear)

Comment: @Seb You need a loop. `tempArray = Split(...)` and then loop from `LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)` or something like that.

Comment: OK thanks. I was just wondering if we could avoid this second loop, so basically it's impossible to store a 1-D array at a given emplacement of a 2-D array. We HAVE TO do it element by element interesting...